# How to correctly send command where CRC is present to Characteristic with web-bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, chromium, crc, web-bluetooth

I got command to be send to BLE device which should look like this:

```
<code>{data}<CRC>
```

Is this type of commands supported by WEB-Bluetooth? If yes how to send it?

What i have tried and failed is that, 
for ex. command should be 'R' and 'data' is optional. So my steps:
1. Convert 'R' to ASCII code
2. For CRC i took from this link http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
'Result CRC value' converted to binary eventually received 2 bytes. 
So i pass it to characteristics:

```
someCahracteristic.writeValue(new Uint8Array([22, 22, 22]));
# Numbers for this example are random
```

tried to set listener 'characteristicvaluechanged' for every available characteristic but no response received.

Any help?

P.S. another my data receiving stuff works great. But commands which works are in different format according to device docs. Problem is only with commands in this format

```
<code>{data}<CRC>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Web Bluetooth's perspective the CRC value is simply part of the value of the characteristic being written, so this should be supported.

Double-check your steps for computing the CRC. The ASCII value of 'R' is 0x52. Does your device expect a CRC-8? CRC-16? If the CRC is multi-byte does it expect it to be little-endian? big-endian?

Comment: Ahh in my case i would have to try all cases and CRC-8 and CRC-16 and maybe some others. can you tell what is the flow i should follow sending this command? lets assume we use CRC-8 and command is 'R', should i send it like new Uint8Array([0x52, 0xFD81]) or should i convert 0xFD81 to binary split it to array of 8 bits and insert it?